# Change case of variable in less file?

Tags: gulp, less

I have added Roboto font for the project and install it by bower, now when run `gulp clean serve`  it's font path location files gives 404 in the console.

after little findings, I came to know that in **bower_components** folder name is `roboto` and font file name is *Roboto-Black.eot* etc  and in the less file *mixin.less* file, there is a function in which `@font-full-path` use below expression

```
.roboto-font(@variant, @type, @weight, @style) {

@font-full-path: '@{roboto-font-path}/@{variant}/@{variant}';
```

Now I want to change first `@{variant}` value from *R*oboto to *r*oboto `@{variant}` keep as `Roboto`

is there any method in `.less` which can change the case ?

Comment: I don't think so (Less is not a text processor). I'm afraid your options are: 1. split `@variant` into separate `name`/`path` vars. 2. Write your custom function [plugin](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/2479) for this (about 7 lines of code). 3. Setup your `gulp` project to rename deployed path or font names to match each other.

Comment: did not get any idea from the link. so long discussion

Comment: if you mean plugin it's [1](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/3.x/test/less/plugin/plugin-simple.js) + [2](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/3.x/test/less/plugin.less#L94-L98)